# PE .idata section

Tags: windows, visual-c++, linker, reverse-engineering, portable-executable

According to the documentation I've read, the import directory for a Windows executable is typically placed in a section called `.idata`. (I know the names are effectively just comments, but 'typically... called' presumably means the Microsoft tool chain will use that name by default.)

When I compile and link a simple C test program with the Microsoft compiler and then dumpbin the result, there is no section called `.idata`. There is, however, in the optional header, a positive RVA and size of import directory, so the import table is there.

Is the import directory nowadays placed in a section with a different name, or am I missing something?

Comment: I have successfully placed the import table outside of any section.  Indeed, one version of my executable has no sections at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, in the executable I just built, there is no `.idata` section.

Using PE Explorer, we can see that the Import Table, and the IAT are stored as part of the `.rdata` section.  (Note the "Pointing Directories" column):

[image]

[image]

On the Data Directories page, we see that the virtual address of the Import Table is `0x403354`. This lands within the range of the `.rdata` section (`0x403000 - 0x403C00`).

---

Interestingly (and somewhat frustratingly), the PE loader for IDA synthetically "creates" an `.idata` section which doesn't *actually* exist in the file:

[image]

Comment: You can uncheck "create imports segment" in the load dialog if you don't want this behavior. But then you may get different analysis results because some code relies on special properties of the `.idata` segment, be it artificial or not.

Comment: Thanks @IgorSkochinsky - I knew I'd seen an option like that at one point, and couldn't immediately remember where it was.  With many options like this, they're helpful - until you forget about the "magic" IDA did while loading, and wonder what the discrepancies with the raw binary are.